# Does express generate default request logs inside a cloud run container? Should I keep them on in my production environment?

Tags: node.js, express, debugging, logging, google-cloud-run

I have an express server inside a Cloud Run Docker container.

I'm getting those logs:

[image]

Are those generated by the `express` package? Or are those logs somehow generated by cloud run?

Here is what express docs says: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/debugging.html

> Express uses the `debug` module internally to log information about route matches, middleware functions that are in use, application mode, and the flow of the request-response cycle.

But it does not give much detail on what those logs are and how you enable or disable them.

Should I leave them on? Won't it hurt my server's performance if it's going to log every request like that? This is `NODE_ENV === "production`.

Comment: It's quite common to log every API request in production so your server should be fine. I know our GCP containers capture anything logged to stdout which are made accessible in stackdriver but we explicitly use pino with express. I'm 99% sure express doesn't log each request by default so it's possibly something you're getting for free from Cloud Run.

Comment: If you want to see what express logs using the debug module, you can set DEBUG=express:* as an env var. https://expressjs.com/en/guide/debugging.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These logs entry are generated by the Cloud Run runtime platform. It's not your Express server. The performance aren't impacted by this log, and in any cases, you can't deactivate them.

You could [exclude them](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/exclusions) to save space in logging capacity (and save money), but I don't recommend this. They brings 3 of [4 golden signals](https://sre.google/sre-book/monitoring-distributed-systems/#xref_monitoring_golden-signals) of your application (error rate, latency, traffic). Very important for production monitoring